# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable, wh

Tags: multithreading, scala, serialization, apache-spark, serializable

When I implemented my own partioner and tried to shuffle the original rdd, I encounter a problem. I know this is caused by referring functions that are not Serializable, but, after adding

> extends Serializable

to every relevent class, this problem still exists. What should I do?

**Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1622)**

```
object STRPartitioner extends Serializable{
  def apply(expectedParNum: Int,
        sampleRate: Double,
        originRdd: RDD[Vertex]): Unit= {
    val bound = computeBound(originRdd)
    val rdd = originRdd.mapPartitions(
      iter => iter.map(row => {
        val cp = row
        (cp.coordinate, cp.copy())
      }
      )
    )
    val partitioner = new STRPartitioner(expectedParNum, sampleRate, bound, rdd)
    val shuffled = new ShuffledRDD[Coordinate, Vertex, Vertex](rdd,  partitioner)
    shuffled.setSerializer(new KryoSerializer(new SparkConf(false)))
    val result = shuffled.collect()
  }

class STRPartitioner(expectedParNum: Int,
                     sampleRate: Double,
                     bound: MBR,
                     rdd: RDD[_ <: Product2[Coordinate, Vertex]])
  extends Partitioner with  Serializable {
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solve the problem! add -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true to your VM config, you will target the unserializable class!